# PyInstaller: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller, openvino

I have a GUI application made using PySide2 and it some major modules it uses are OpenVino(2019), dlib, OpenCV-contrib(4.2.x) and Postgres(psycopg2) and I am trying to freeze the application using PyInstaller (--debug is True).

The program gets frozen without errors but during execution, I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

after which the application exits.

I have tried many suggestions provided in other stackoverflow questions/github issues but none of them have worked.

I have python version 3.7.6 but I have also tried with 3.6.8 (both local installation and after creating new venv in pycharm). I have tried different versions of pycharm as well(it shows som other errors below 3.5). I have tried pycharm 3.6 both develop branch and master branch.

I have checked my PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME in env variables, they are pointing to python's location.

I have modified my specfile to include the necessary binaries, files, imports and folders. I would share it if needed. Also any other logs during build or execution.

I would like to know what I should do to solve this, wheather this issue is because of some component or is this a PyInstaller issue, and if so, should I raise it on github.

My os is windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You changed the python version. So, you have to give a new path according to the Python version.
Just remove all older version and the current one and reinstall new Python v.3.8.1

Comment: I removed older versions after uninstalling them, there is only one version in my path right now (3.7.6). I don't want to use 3.8 as there are modules which currently don't properly support 3.8 (like pyinstaller)

Comment: Just delete and add environment variables again.

Comment: Check whether you have installed the libraries in the virtual env.

Comment: Yes, I had frozen the requirements and I reinstalled them in venv. My application works properly before freezing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include base_library.zip in your application folder